# Children's books from the 80s about a professor who used his smoking pipe to teleport himself, a girl and a boy to other worlds?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, teleportation

I can’t remember the name of these books, but they are old sci-fi children's books from the 80s about a professor who used his smoking pipe to teleport himself, a girl (I think his niece or grand daughter) and a boy through space to other worlds.

One story I remember was about them being teleported to a stadium in space that had three Suns.

Comment: Hi Justin, Welcome to Stackexchange ! Thank for posting a question with a helpful description in the title, and giving us the date!

Comment: +1 I had these books too. I _think_ they were Ladybird books. One of them ended with the boy having a neverending chocolate bar IIRC.

Comment: @PhilPursglove They were indeed Ladybird books.

Answer (score 14):

This was the Professor Gamma series, written by the astronomer [Sir Fred Hoyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Hoyle) and his son [Geoffrey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Hoyle) and published by Ladybird (in the UK, at least, and I recall them being quite British in a Professor Quatermass/Doctor Who style, so I think it's unlikely they were published elsewhere). The series of four books was:

- [The Frozen Planet of Azuron](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/h/geoffrey-hoyle/frozen-planet-of-azuron.htm)
- [The Planet of Death](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/h/geoffrey-hoyle/planet-of-death.htm)
- [The Giants of Universal Park](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/h/geoffrey-hoyle/giants-of-universal-park.htm)
- [The Energy Pirate](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/h/geoffrey-hoyle/energy-pirate.htm)

Comment: +1 Was just about to post that, you got there first :)